# How to sync/backup "my documents" to Google Drive

Tags: google, synchronization, backup, google-drive

Google Drive (at $2.49 for 25gb) seems like a great option for cloud storage. But I'm looking for a program to backup/mirror/sync my documents folder to Google Drive.

I've been looking for backup/sync with android mobile access to email attachments, etc. and Google Drive may fit the bill.

is there a program to sync drives to Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get synchronized backups to my Google Drive, I've done the following:

- Map the Google Drive as a network Drive

I also looked at many different programs/apps to get automatic live synchronization.

There are a ton of different synchronization apps, but most are manual (or run on a schedule).

There are very few "live" synchronization apps.

Currently, I am testing [PureSync](http://www.jumpingbytes.com/en/puresync/features.html) - I've tested it with just a few files, and it's worked flawlessly. It has a lot of synchronization options:

- Synchronize on file modification, schedule, startup, etc.
- delete behavior
- hierarchy
- directional capabilities
- etc.

I am going to test further, and will write up my findings.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options. One is to change the location of "My Documents" to be the "Google Drive" folder (Hint:right click on "My Documents">>"Properties"). The second is to mike a link. To do this:

1. Shut down Google Drive (I had to uninstall it)
2. Move everything out of your "My Documents" folder (but leave the folder)
3. Open a command prompt as administrator, cd to `C:\Users\%user%\`
4. Run the command `mklink /j "Google Drive" Documents`
5. Restart (install) Google Drive
6. Move your stuff back into "My Documents"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program like "ViceVersa PRO" which provides both manual and automatic live synchronization with your Google Drive folder: http://www.tgrmn.com

Answer (score -1):

Schedule robocopy, which is part of Windows 7, to copy differential files to the Google Drive folder.